# CREACION DE LISTBOX DINAMICOS CON LISTA ENLAZADA C#

Tags: c#

Necesito crear una listbox por cada valor en mi lista enlazada. Con este código, si creo varias fechas previo a la ejecución del btnSort, y luego lo ejecuto, crea las listas correctamente. Sin embargo, al crear una nueva fecha, y ejecutar la función btnSort nuevamente, quedan las mismas listas creadas anteriormente y no genera la lista recientemente agregada.

Ejemplo de ejecucion del codigo:

Se carga una fecha

Se carga otra fecha

Ejecutamos la funcion btnSort

Se agregan las listas al form

Se carga una nueva fecha

Ejecutamos la funcion btnSort

No se agrega nada nuevo, quedan las listas ya agregadas con anterioridad.

```
 private void CreateLists(NodeListBox node)
 {
     int locationY = 51;
     int width = 139;
     int height = 264;

     NodeListBox current = node;

     while (current != null)
     {
         if (!Controls.ContainsKey(node.Name))
         {
             locationX += width + 10;
             Label label = new Label();
             label.Text = node.Name;
             label.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY - 26);

             ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
             listBox.Name = node.Name;
             listBox.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
             listBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
             Controls.Add(listBox);
             Controls.Add(label);
         }

         current = current.Next;
     }
 }

 private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (listBoxes.Init != null)
     {
         CreateLists(listBoxes.Init);
     }
 }
```

Comment: si controls ya contiene la key, no va a crear nada... suponiendo que este ande, en algun momento estas borrando los listbox viejos???

Comment: No estoy limpiando los listbox, deberia limpiarlos y agregarlos nuevamente con la nueva listbox agregada?

Comment: Y... no se.. o por lo menos, saber la posicion de la ultima agregada.. cuando entras por segunda vez, en que posicion FISICA agrega el nuevo? me parece que te queda abajo de los que estan...